# Can blender do "deep compositing"?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

[Maxwell Render explanation of deep render and showcase of it](http://www.maxwellrender.com/V3/feature/deepcompositing)

Was wondering, can Blender do "Deep" rendering to EXR, where an EXR file has 3D depth to it? If you go to `1:50` of the video you will see what deep rendering is in it's full awesomeness.

Comment: I'm not really sure what makes the image "3D" in the Maxwell render, but I know that you can fake lighting in Blender if you render out the normal pass kinda like they were doing in the video.

Comment: Deep Render is part of the OpenEXR 2 format. As far as I know there's no support for it on blender yet.

Comment: Not quite, their is the z-depth hack, but their is no true deep compositeing method to-date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get depth information and use it the compositor (e.g. with the [Z combine node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Color#Z-Combine_Node)) or put it in an EXR layer.

However there is no support currently for true deep compositing, which allows for transparency and compositing tricky things such as a motion blurred object.

I don't see it on any of the todos, however it's being [mentioned](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-cycles/2014-May/001944.html) in the mailing lists a bit, so it's hopefully only a matter of time.

---

If all you need is depth information, then it's currently possible:

The Z output contains depth information. It appears white since most of it's values are greater than 1. To view it, you need to map it's range to the 0-1 range, so you can use a *Map range* node or a *Normalize* node:

[image]

If you want to put it in an EXR, enable *Z buffer* in *Render settings > Output*:

[image]

You can use this with the Z combine node, which combines images based on Z depth values. For example, with two renderlayers (one with a sphere and one with some random objects), I can render them separately and then combine them almost as if I rendered them as one:

[image]

Comment: Deep is more than Deph information... You are able to create 3D Masks and 3D Compositing. You Can move 2D Rendered Images with Deep Channels in 3D Space. Relighting of scenes with 3d Lights and so on!